# Ruby - Parse dependencies data from Podfile.lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, json

I have a sample podfile.lock as below:

```
PODS:
- MyLibrary1 (0.10.0):
  - MyLibrary1A (>= 0.9.0)
- AFNetworking (1.1.0)
- MyLibrary2 (3.0.0)
- Objective-C-HMTL-Parser (0.0.1)

DEPENDENCIES:
- MyLibrary1 (= 0.10.0)
- AFNetworking (= 1.1.0)
- MyLibrary2 (= 3.0.0)
- Objective-C-HMTL-Parser (= 0.0.1)

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  MyLibrary1: 1d65fa5d905211c8981a11091eae8c98b410eb19
  AFNetworking: 761a418233d280c1e0580bcb76ff9cb4c3073d17
  MyLibrary2: 35b80d5cc522b0f53beb5583c635e42ecce69743
  Objective-C-HMTL-Parser: 4fca85e186a829cfe8db8e316e9688571ea4dfed

COCOAPODS: 0.16.9
```

***REQUIREMENT:***

I want the data between dependency data in a JSON format i.e. something like:

```
{
"MyLibrary1": "0.10.0",
"AFNetworking": "1.1.0",
"MyLibrary2": "3.0.0",
"Objective-C-HMTL-Parser": "0.0.1"
}
```

***WHAT I DID:***

I am trying to get the data in the "DEPENDENCIES:" first using regex:

```
  start_string = "DEPENDENCIES:"
  end_string = "SPEC CHECKSUMS:"
  file_contents[/#{start_string}(.*?)#{end_string}/m, 1]
```

With this I get:

```
"\n  - MyLibrary1 (= 0.10.0)\n  - AFNetworking (= 1.1.0)\n  - MyLibrary2 (= 3.0.0)\n  - Objective-C-HMTL-Parser (= 0.0.1)\n\n"
```

***QUESTION:***

With the above posted result of regex, how/whats the easy way to get/separate "MyLibrary1" and "0.10.0" to make a JSON?

Comment: Don't know how you got that result using multi-line modifier, but usually this action you seek requires two regexes. On you already have, then another to parse that result for each key/value.

Comment: I am working on the second regex on rubular right now. I was trying to find if there is any easier way to achieve this.

Comment: Not really any faster way, unless Python supports the `\G` construct or does `Capture Collections` (unique to Dot-Net).

Comment: @sln: in Ruby the m modifier is equivalent to the s modifier in PCRE.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - Thanks for info, I never found an in-depth documentation on Ruby regex constructs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `\G` anchor that marks the position at the end of the last match:

[rubular](http://rubular.com/r/R5PjYXiwOa)

```
data.scan /(?:\G(?!\A)|^DEPENDENCIES:\n)- (\S+) \(= ([^)]+)\)\n/
=> [["MyLibrary1", "0.10.0"], ["AFNetworking", "1.1.0"], ["MyLibrary2", "3.0.0"], ["Objective-C-HMTL-Parser", "0.0.1"]]
```

Comment: +1 So Ruby does support the `\G` anchor. Is it like Perl, can it do recursion/conditionals/branch_reset ?

Comment: @sln: It can do recursion, conditionals, but not branch reset. It has the `\K` feature too.